# Re-order 2-dimensional array using keys and values from one-dimensional array with php

Tags: php, arrays

i am having a 2-dimensional array $a like this:

```
Array (
 [1] => Array ( 
 [id] => 19 
 [name] => SomeName 
),
[2] => Array ( 
 [id] => 23 
 [name] => AnotherName 
),
[3] => Array ( 
 [id] => 45 
 [name] => OneMoreName 
) 
)
```

And the second array $b like this:

```
Array (  
[0] => 45 
[1] => 23 
[2] => 19 
)
```

The values of 2nd array are id's from first array. The order of elements is right in 2nd array, but is not right in 1st. So, i want to re-order elements in 1st array to have finally:

```
Array (
 [1] => Array ( 
 [id] => 45 
 [name] => OneMoreName 
),
[2] => Array ( 
 [id] => 23 
 [name] => AnotherName 
),
[3] => Array ( 
 [id] => 19
 [name] => SomeName 
) 
)
```

Of course, the number of elements can be more than 3, but in both arrays it is always the same. What standart php function or what approach can i use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some array_walk function, but to be more understandable, i would use a specific algorithm:

```
    $array1 = [
        ['id' => 19, 'name' => 'name19'],
        ['id' => 23, 'name' => 'name23'],
        ['id' => 45, 'name' => 'name45'],
    ];
    $array2 = [45, 23, 19];
    $newArray1 = [];
    
    foreach ($array1 as $data){
        // Get the array key from array2 with strict comparison value
        $newKey = array_search($data['id'], $array2, true);
        // Set it in a new array temporary
        $newArray1[$newKey] = $data;
    }
    $array1 = $newArray1;
```

This way is quite short and easily understandable by someone else

Comment: this is what i need, just used `array_search($data['id'], $array2, false);` instead of `array_search($data['id'], $array2, true);` in my case, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you liked the solution, please upvote it and/or flag it as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

One simple way:

```
$result = array_merge(array_flip($b), array_column($a, null, 'id'));
```

- Index `$a` on the `id` and flip `$b` to get the values as the index
- Merge the existing array into the ordered one, which will replace in the proper order

If you need to re-index then use `array_values`:

```
$result = array_values(array_merge(array_flip($b), array_column($a, null, 'id')));
```

I didn't test it but you could probably use `array_intersect_key` instead of `array_merge`.

Comment: ...this also works! Fantastic!